# Flex app loads in ie/chrome but not in firefox (hosted on Azure)

Tags: apache-flex, azure, flash, loading

What I'm seeing is the browser loads the html and shows a blank white page.  If I change the swfobject background color to black, I see the black square.  For larger swf's I see a progress bar that proceeds to 100% and then just stops.

I boiled this down to a simple hello world app and it still fails for me.  It only seems to fail when the SWF file is served by a hosted web server instance on Azure.  Oddly when loading the html directly into the browser from the file system it works - just not when hosted on Azure.  It also fails when running the emulator.  I just tried putting the file into blob storage and that works perfectly in all browsers. I have not tried the file on another host.

Here is the html - very plain and generic.  All generated from flash builder.  Ignore the fact that it is called ClientPreloader.swf - I've removed all functionality now so it is just a single label on the stage.

As for Azure, it is hosted on SP2 and I have not made any changes to the running IE.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en"> 
        <!-- 
        Smart developers always View Source. 

        This application was built using Adobe Flex, an open source framework
        for building rich Internet applications that get delivered via the
        Flash Player or to desktops via Adobe AIR. 

        Learn more about Flex at http://flex.org 
        // -->
        <head>
            <title></title>
            <meta name="google" value="notranslate" />         
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <!-- Include CSS to eliminate any default margins/padding and set the height of the html element and 
                 the body element to 100%, because Firefox, or any Gecko based browser, interprets percentage as 
                 the percentage of the height of its parent container, which has to be set explicitly.  Fix for
                 Firefox 3.6 focus border issues.  Initially, don't display flashContent div so it won't show 
                 if JavaScript disabled.
            -->
            <style type="text/css" media="screen"> 
                html, body  { height:100%; }
                body { margin:0; padding:0; overflow:auto; text-align:center; 
                       background-color: #ffffff; }   
                object:focus { outline:none; }
                #flashContent { display:none; }
            </style>

            <!-- Enable Browser History by replacing useBrowserHistory tokens with two hyphens -->
            <!-- BEGIN Browser History required section -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="history/history.css" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="history/history.js"></script>
            <!-- END Browser History required section -->  

            <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                // For version detection, set to min. required Flash Player version, or 0 (or 0.0.0), for no version detection. 
                var swfVersionStr = "11.1.0";
                // To use express install, set to playerProductInstall.swf, otherwise the empty string. 
                var xiSwfUrlStr = "playerProductInstall.swf";
                var flashvars = {};
                var params = {};
                params.quality = "high";
                params.bgcolor = "#ffffff";
                params.allowscriptaccess = "sameDomain";
                params.allowfullscreen = "true";
                var attributes = {};
                attributes.id = "ClientPreloader";
                attributes.name = "ClientPreloader";
                attributes.align = "middle";
                swfobject.embedSWF(
                    "ClientPreloader.swf", "flashContent", 
                    "100%", "100%", 
                    swfVersionStr, xiSwfUrlStr, 
                    flashvars, params, attributes);
                // JavaScript enabled so display the flashContent div in case it is not replaced with a swf object.
                swfobject.createCSS("#flashContent", "display:block;text-align:left;");
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <!-- SWFObject's dynamic embed method replaces this alternative HTML content with Flash content when enough 
                 JavaScript and Flash plug-in support is available. The div is initially hidden so that it doesn't show
                 when JavaScript is disabled.
            -->
            <div id="flashContent">
                <p>
                    To view this page ensure that Adobe Flash Player version 
                    11.1.0 or greater is installed. 
                </p>
                <script type="text/javascript"> 
                    var pageHost = ((document.location.protocol == "https:") ? "https://" : "http://"); 
                    document.write("<a href='http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer'><img src='" 
                                    + pageHost + "www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif' alt='Get 

Adobe Flash player' /></a>" ); 
                </script> 
            </div>

            <noscript>
                <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="100%" height="100%" id="ClientPreloader">
                    <param name="movie" value="ClientPreloader.swf" />
                    <param name="quality" value="high" />
                    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
                    <!--[if !IE]>-->
                    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="ClientPreloader.swf" width="100%" height="100%">
                        <param name="quality" value="high" />
                        <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
                    <!--<![endif]-->
                    <!--[if gte IE 6]>-->
                        <p> 
                            Either scripts and active content are not permitted to run or Adobe Flash Player version
                            11.1.0 or greater is not installed.
                        </p>
                    <!--<![endif]-->
                        <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
                            <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe 

Flash Player" />
                        </a>
                    <!--[if !IE]>-->
                    </object>
                    <!--<![endif]-->
                </object>
            </noscript>     
       </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real answer to this questing seems to be "don't do that".  I'm disappointed not to see any responses here.  My scientific approach to Azure ended up biting me.  I was trying to take on one feature at a time (hosted IE, then storage, etc).  The key to getting it to work is doing everything.  You need to embrace all of Azure.  Granted there is an obvious defect in the hosted IIS related to the SWF file.  But if you follow the recommendations fully - put large files in storage, etc.  It all works smoothly (faster even).

Comment: In Flex 4 and above, the SWF is compiled by default to use RSL's. It leaves the Flex framework class out of your app SWF. Flash Player will download/cache the framekwork RSL's. I would start to trouble shoot this aspect first. You can compile the swf w/out RSL's (it will be a bigger SWF, but the loading process will have fewer moving parts).

Comment: I've compiled this with and without all RSL's included. I've also compiled with FlashDevelop. All of the files are present in the directory. To this point, it works in IE and Chrome. I'm sure this is an IIS setting of some sort that both the emulator and web instance share by default.

Comment: I kept searching the web and finally found this helpful article. Turns out it was a FluorineFX setting and not anything to do with Azure. The default configuration has FlouorineFX compressing responses and it seems to not be compatible with Firefox. By adding '<excludedMimeTypes><add type="application/swf" /></excludedMimeTypes>' to the httpCompress section the problem went away. [Here is the full article explaining it](http://blog.johlero.eu/2010/09/26/white-screen-when-loading-flash-in-firefox-gzip-problem/).